# Sum integer field

Tags: python, django-models

I have this model field and each employee add record,(Adeia=dayoff, holidays). How can I count the days for each employee and pass the result to a template. I'm stuck with that.

```
class Adeia(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',max_length=100, verbose_name='Υπάλληλος',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adeiatype = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=adeia_choice, verbose_name='Τύπος Άδειας', blank=True, default='-' )
    startdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,verbose_name='Από')
    enddate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,verbose_name='Έως')
    createddate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,verbose_name='Ημ. Δημουργίας')
    days = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ημέρες', null=False,blank=False, default='0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your Adeia by employees and return the sum of days for each employee.

This should work:

```
from django.db.models import *
Adeia.objects.values('employee').annotate(days_sum=Sum('days'))
```

This will give you a dictionary where first key is employee with an id value, and the second key is sum_of_days with total days by that employee.
Something like this: `<QuerySet [{'employee': 1, 'days_sum': 0}, {'employee': 2, 'days_sum': 0}]>`

Hope this helps!